# Pattern to communicate across component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All:

I am just start second day study of React.js, currently what I want to do is:

A standard 2 columns layout: 
A menu on the left and a content body on the right.

The behaviors are:

1. click the item in the left menu, according section in the content body will scroll to the top.
2. Scroll the body content, when certain section reach top( or the vertical center ), the according item in the menu will highlight.

I wonder how to implement this in React way.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the flux pattern.

Comment: @pherris Thanks, I am pretty new to this. Could you briefly give a little explain about flux and how does it apply to my case?

Comment: Essentially it's a pattern for changing state within your stores. Each component will react to whatever it's current state is and render properly.  Here is a great overview on Flux: http://www.code-experience.com/async-requests-with-react-js-and-flux-revisited/

Comment: I think you can get around this by just having a common parent component storing the current section to show. When you click on an item on the left, the component rendering this list of items will notify the parent to set the clicked section as the current section. The component on the right will notify the parent each time a new div is reach through scrolling. No need to use Flux.

Comment: @pherris Thanks I will read that.

Comment: @JeremyD THansk. One thing I am wonderfing is How can I make the parent component know the change from children component? Should the children component has property variable to accepty a variable or function from parent?

Comment: Your parent will always pass two props to those two child. One prop to give the current section id and a callback to call when the child wants to notify the parent of a section change (either when you click or scroll). The component that are children do not need to store anything on their state. They are just dumb components getting data and rendering depending on the section id they get.